# AVAudioPlayer not responding

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, avaudioplayer

I initialize an AVAudioPlayer instance:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"wav"];

AVAudioPlayer* player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:nil]; //Returned object not nil, indicating that the file has loaded successfully


BOOL b = [player prepareToPlay]; //returns TRUE

BOOL b2 = [player play]; 
//returns TRUE, goes immediately to the next line since asynchronous


[NSThread sleepUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]; //wait 1 sec

printf("%10.4f\n",player.duration); //duration is 2s

printf("%10.4f\n",player.currentTime); //position remains 0

/* There is no sound output, player is also stuck since position==0 */
```

Does anyone know why the AVAudioPlayer is not responding? Is there something that I am overlooking while initializing, playing the audioplayer? Boilerplate code maybe?

I am running this on the iPhone simulator. Also, AudioServicesPlaySystemSound() works for the same file, which is puzzling, but this indicates that sound playback might work with AVAudioPlayer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 quick suggestions:

1. Check to see if that path actually gives you data. Alloc a NSData object using [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] and inspect it in the debugger to see if you're actually loading that wav file.
2. I wrote a sample project that uses AVAudioPlayer here: [AVAudioPlayer Example](http://9mmedia.com/blog/?p=308). As the code is pretty much the same as yours, the only thing I can imagine is that there is a problem with your data.

Check those out and see if it gets you anywhere!

Answer (score 2):

I have just had a similar problem.  I am not sure if it is the same solution, but my application records audio through the iphone and then plays it back to the user.

I thought I was doing the correct thing by telling my audio session that it was going to record data, so I did the following:

```
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
```

Using this setting playback worked on the Simulator but not on the device.... the didFinishPlaying event never got raised.

I removed this line after realising I didn't need it an audio playback started working correctly.  Now I just need to work out why it is so quiet :)

Paul